# How to run with Flutter background processes after the device reboot?

Tags: flutter

I am using WorkManager in order to run some background processes for my app. However when the device is restarted, the background processes are not more there and I need to re-open the app to restart them. How can I restart automatically the processes in background after the reboot without opening the app again?